# Xpath all following-siblings

Tags: html, xpath

I am using DOMXpath to query a table on a another site. What I want to do is take the table and layout the info in a XML format.

Here is the table that I want to gather info from *(note: there are a varying amount of players, but the same amount of info per player)*.

```
<table id="report" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="font-weight:bold;"> TEAM 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Player 1</td>
            <td>Average</td>
            <td>Other info</td>
            <td>More info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Player 2</td>
            <td>Average</td>
            <td>Other info</td>
            <td>More info</td>
        </tr>
        ...
        <tr>
            <td colspan="22" style="font-weight:bold;"> TEAM 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Player 1</td>
            <td>Average</td>
            <td>Other info</td>
            <td>More info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Player 2</td>
            <td>Average</td>
            <td>Other info</td>
            <td>More info</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My PHP so far is as follows:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('table.html');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$league = $xpath->query('//table[7]/tbody/tr/td[contains(@style,"bold")]');

$xml = new DOMDocument();

foreach($league as $teams) {
    $team = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement("team"));

    $teamname = $xpath->query('.', $teams)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $team->appendChild($xml->createElement("teamname", $teamname));

    $members = $xpath->query('../following-sibling::tr', $teams);

    foreach($members as $player) {

        $member = $team->appendChild($xml->createElement("member"));

        $name = $xpath->query('./td[1]', $player)->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $member->appendChild($xml->createElement("name", $name));
    }

}

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

I would like to save it in XML format like so:

```
<team>
    <teamname>Team 1</teamname>
    <member>
        <name>Player 1</name>
        <average>Average</average>
        <stats-one>Other info</stats-one>
        <stats-two>More info</stats-two>
    </member>
    <member>
        <name>Player 2</name>
        <average>Average</average>
        <stats-one>Other info</stats-one>
        <stats-two>More info</stats-two>
    </member>
    ...
<team>
<team>
    <teamname>Team 2</teamname>
    <member>
        <name>Player 1</name>
        <average>Average</average>
        <stats-one>Other info</stats-one>
        <stats-two>More info</stats-two>
    </member>
    <member>
        <name>Player 2</name>
        <average>Average</average>
        <stats-one>Other info</stats-one>
        <stats-two>More info</stats-two>
    </member>
    ...
<team>
```

EDIT: I wrote a foreach that works to a certain extent. I am getting the information that I want but it is not stopping before the start of the next team, instead it gets every td, then continues onto the next team and gets every td from taht point down etc, etc.
At the end of each team's information is a  with a value of "Team Totals". I would like for the foreach to stop before that.
I have tried something similar to what Oleksii Matiiasevych suggested but it just gives me the first member on the team.

```
foreach($members as $player) {

        $member = $team->appendChild($xml->createElement("member"));

        $name = $xpath->query('./td[1]', $player)->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $member->appendChild($xml->createElement("name", $name));

        if($name = "Team Totals") break;
    }
```

Comment: You're not iterating over the players that are found, instead only taking the first one and using it ```$name = $xpath->query('../following-sibling::tr/td', $teams)->item(0)->nodeValue;```

Comment: I figured that was the problem. I'm a n00b to all of this, so how would I go about iterating over the players?

Comment: Learn how to code php, then come back to the module. however, I will spoon feed you for now - you'd use a foreach, just like you have before it (though I assume that was a copy/paste from another person?)

Comment: @user3791372 I believe that I speak for the Stack Exchange community as a whole when telling you to please keep your snarky put-down comments to yourself. This venue is a place to seek advice and share knowledge among both experts and novices.

Comment: Allow me to welcome you to Stack Exchange.You posted a question and an upvoted solution was offered.A question then asking how to code such a simple solution is frowned upon.You need to carry the weight of your own problem.Basic questions about a language are usually downvoted and closed.Stack Ex. is not a place for asking how to use a foreach.Clearly, what you want is more spoon-feeding than advice (which again, is frowned upon).The advice of learning the basics of PHP before coding it is perhaps the most important advice you'll read in this question as there are many terrible PHP coders.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to iterate over members `$members = $xpath->query('../following-sibling::tr', $teams);`, but only 2 times cause there only 2 players(and much more following tr's):

```
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
    // inside this loop.
}
```

Inside this loop you need to create member node(so it will be created 2 times) as you did before `$member = $team->appendChild($xml->createElement("member"));`, then access current player `$player = $members->item($i);`, and then you can access this player attributes `$playerAttrs = $xpath->query('./td', $player);`, after this you need to create nodes for your 4 attributes, and at last put in it one of the `$playerAttrs->item(0|1|2|3)->nodeValue` accordingly.

EDIT: If there is unknown number of players, then solution for iteration changes a bit:

```
foreach($members as $player) {
    $playerAttrs = $xpath->query('td', $player);
    if ($playerAttrs->length == 1) {
        break; // Break on next Team Name node
    }

    $member = $team->appendChild($xml->createElement("member"));

    // not sure part
    $statCounter = 0;
    foreach($playerAttrs as $attr) {
        $member->appendChild($xml->createElement("stats-{$statCounter}", $attr->nodeValue));
        $statCounter++;
    }
    // end of not sure part
}
```

Still you need to specify somehow names for each player attribute, cause there is no such information in the input xml. Or if you ok with `<stats-1>`, `<stats-2>`, etc. then end of the loop may look like in `// not sure part`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately I don't believe your solution will work due to my improper explanation. The number of players varies by team and could change on a weekly basis, so I am looking for more of a foreach solution. As for the player attributes there will be 20 some stats that I want to report for each player.